# Hibernate setMaxResults throws SQLServerException: index 1 is out of range

Tags: hibernate

I am in the middle of migrating Hibernate from 3.2.6 to 5.2. I am trying to use the new org.hibernate.query.Query api over deprecated org.hibernate.Query. The old api works just fine, but when I change it to new API, the query fails with the following exception

```
SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range
```

If I comment out `setMaxResults`, every thing works fine. Debugging the sources shows it is trying to apply `LIMIT` clause and fails. The generated SQL already has `TOP 8` after `select` clause, then why is it trying to apply the LIMIT clause?

I think it is a bug in the latest sources. What am I missing?
I think its a bug in Hibernate, How do I file an issue with hibernate?

Comment: Related question
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785942/sqlserverexception-the-index-1-is-out-of-range-when-executiong-spring-data-find)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the sql server dialect to SQLServer2008Dialect fixed the issue. Created blog post [here](https://gonelive.blogspot.com/2017/03/hibernate-setmaxresults-throws.html).

Answer (score 0):

Update hibernate version to 5.2.9:

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.9.Final</hibernate.version>
```

It was a hibernate's bug :https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11503