# SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range when executiong Spring Data findAll(Pageable)

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jhipster

When the Spring Data findAll(Pageable) method of an entity is called, the following query is executed by Hibernate:

```
select TOP(?) customer0_.id as id1_0_, customer0_.name as name2_0_ from customer customer0_
```

After that the following query is executed:

```
Hibernate: select customer0_.id as id1_0_, customer0_.name as name2_0_ from customer customer0_ order by customer0_.id asc offset 0 rows fetch next 20 rows only
```

An execption is raised

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not execute query [select customer0_.id as id1_0_, customer0_.name as name2_0_ from customer customer0_ order by customer0_.id asc]

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:940)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:954)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setInt(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1249)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setInt(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.SQLServer2005LimitHandler.bindLimitParametersAtStartOfQuery(SQLServer2005LimitHandler.java:132)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1950)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:370)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1481)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1441)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:589)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:409)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:377)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.findAll(Unknown Source)
at sa.tvtc.farm.web.rest.CustomerResource.getAllCustomers(CustomerResource.java:107)
at sa.tvtc.farm.web.rest.CustomerResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$48eccfb1.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at sa.tvtc.farm.web.rest.CustomerResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b6861c0.getAllCustomers(<generated>)
```

Configuration:

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
 ...
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    database: SQL_SERVER
```

pom.xml

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<hikaricp.version>2.6.0</hikaricp.version>
<mssql-jdbc.version>6.1.0.jre8</mssql-jdbc.version>
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.sabomichal</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-mssql</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase-mssql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of previous version of Hibernate fixed the problem

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This worked for me. However its does not seem clean. Have you found another way ? Is this an hibernate bug ?

Comment: Yes it's a bug in Hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HHH-11572